# matching specific word with strings in list. fully matched and not partially

Tags: python

```
delete = ["man", "eat"]

item_list = ['sharper_task|$none_venue|man', 'sharper_task|man_venue|king', 'sharper_task|king_venue|world', 'sharper_task|world_venue|dont', 'sharper_task|を_venue|eater', 'sharper_task|eater_venue|todo', 'sharper_task|todo_venue|,']
```

My code:

```
lst = []
for x in item_list:
    if not any(y in x for y in delete):
        lst.append([x, x])

print(lst)
```

However, this method will render my output become very troublesome. For an example, if my delete contains delete = ["man", "eat"] which is not similar for the word "eater" within item_list but still, the program will take it since I use if not any(y IN x) this "in" will return true since eat contains within eater but what I wanted isnt containing within the word but the matching. I would like to match the word eater to eater and man to man and not eat to eater and ma to man.

Is there a way to do a fully matching and not partially?? My current code take partially matched which is so wrong when I have many partial words within delete.

Answer (score 1):

Then you can check for exact match of strings:

```
    delete = ["man", "eat"]

    item_list = ['sharper_task|$none_venue|man', 'sharper_task|man_venue|king', 'sharper_task|king_venue|world', 'sharper_task|world_venue|dont', 'sharper_task|を_venue|eater', 'sharper_task|eater_venue|todo', 'sharper_task|todo_venue|,']


    lst = []
    for x in item_list:
        if not any(y == x for y in delete):
            lst.append([x, x])

    print(lst)


#  [['sharper_task|$none_venue|man', 'sharper_task|$none_venue|man'], ['sharper_task|man_venue|king', 'sharper_task|man_venue|king'], ['sharper_task|king_venue|world', 'sharper_task|king_venue|world'], ['sharper_task|world_venue|dont', 'sharper_task|world_venue|dont'], ['sharper_task|を_venue|eater', 'sharper_task|を_venue|eater'], ['sharper_task|eater_venue|todo', 'sharper_task|eater_venue|todo'], ['sharper_task|todo_venue|,', 'sharper_task|todo_venue|,']]
```

Note: The `or |` operator isn't of any use inside a string like in `'sharper_task|eater_venue|todo'`.

Comment: Is there a way to split "sharper_task|man_venue-1_0_king" to "sharper", "","task", "|", "man", "", "venue","-","1","","0","","king"?

Comment: @Beginner can you post the output you are expecting?

Answer (score 1):

You can split the strings with `|` into substrings first before using the `in` operator to test if items in `delete` is in one of the substrings further split from the prior substrings with `_`:

```
lst = []
for x in item_list:
    if not any(y in s.split('_') for s in x.split('|') for y in delete):
        lst.append([x, x])
print(lst)
```

This outputs:

`[['sharper_task|man_venue|king', 'sharper_task|man_venue|king'], ['sharper_task|king_venue|world', 'sharper_task|king_venue|world'], ['sharper_task|world_venue|dont', 'sharper_task|world_venue|dont'], ['sharper_task|を_venue|eater', 'sharper_task|を_venue|eater'], ['sharper_task|eater_venue|todo', 'sharper_task|eater_venue|todo'], ['sharper_task|todo_venue|,', 'sharper_task|todo_venue|,']]`

Comment: True but now the man is inside the output as well. the "man" should not be inside the output.

Comment: Is there a way to split "sharper_task|man_venue-1_0_king" to "sharper", "_","task", "|", "man", "_", "venue","-","1","_","0","_","king"?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking to split on the pipe character,

```
delete = ["man", "eat"]

item_list = ['sharper_task|$none_venue|man', 'sharper_task|man_venue|king', 'sharper_task|king_venue|world', 'sharper_task|world_venue|dont', 'sharper_task|を_venue|eater', 'sharper_task|eater_venue|todo', 'sharper_task|todo_venue|,']

lst = [item 
       for item in item_list 
       if any(word in item.split('|') for word in delete)]
```

Comment: Is there a way to split "sharper_task|man_venue-1_0_king" to "sharper", "","task", "|", "man", "", "venue","-","1","","0","","king"?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below -

```
import re

del_list = ["man", "eat"]
regex = '|'.join([r'\b' + y + r'\b' for y in del_list])

item_list = ['sharper_task|$none_venue|man', 'sharper_task|man_venue|king', 'sharper_task|king_venue|world', 'sharper_task|world_venue|dont', 'sharper_task|を_venue|eater', 'sharper_task|eater_venue|todo', 'sharper_task|todo_venue|,']

lst = []
for x in item_list:
  if not re.search(regex, x):
      lst.append([x, x])

print(lst)
```

Output of this -

```
[['sharper_task|man_venue|king', 'sharper_task|man_venue|king'], ['sharper_task|king_venue|world', 'sharper_task|king_venue|world'], ['sharper_task|world_venue|dont', 'sharper_task|world_venue|dont'], ['sharper_task|を_venue|eater', 'sharper_task|を_venue|eater'], ['sharper_task|eater_venue|todo', 'sharper_task|eater_venue|todo'], ['sharper_task|todo_venue|,', 'sharper_task|todo_venue|,']]
```

Using one single Regular Expression rather than a list ensures that the match for each "to be deleted" item does not introduce an item_list element into the output list which was removed by the earlier "to be deleted" item.

The regex = '|'.join() - Here it's creating a regular expression using raw (r'') strings with '\b' to match the word boundaries (identified by non-alphanumeric chars). Read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html)

If we use 2 for loops one for del_list and another for item_list then the output will look as below, which I think is incorrect as "man" list still appears once because of the "eat" did not match. Rest of the items that did not match even one of the del_list appear twice -

```
[['sharper_task|$none_venue|man', 'sharper_task|$none_venue|man'], ['sharper_task|man_venue|king', 'sharper_task|man_venue|king'], ['sharper_task|man_venue|king', 'sharper_task|man_venue|king'], ['sharper_task|king_venue|world', 'sharper_task|king_venue|world'], ['sharper_task|king_venue|world', 'sharper_task|king_venue|world'], ['sharper_task|world_venue|dont', 'sharper_task|world_venue|dont'], ['sharper_task|world_venue|dont', 'sharper_task|world_venue|dont'], ['sharper_task|を_venue|eater', 'sharper_task|を_venue|eater'], ['sharper_task|を_venue|eater', 'sharper_task|を_venue|eater'], ['sharper_task|eater_venue|todo', 'sharper_task|eater_venue|todo'], ['sharper_task|eater_venue|todo', 'sharper_task|eater_venue|todo'], ['sharper_task|todo_venue|,', 'sharper_task|todo_venue|,'], ['sharper_task|todo_venue|,', 'sharper_task|todo_venue|,']]
```

Comment: Is there a way to split "sharper_task|man_venue-1_0_king" to "sharper", "","task", "|", "man", "", "venue","-","1","","0","","king"?

Comment: The logic for doing this can be to replace all underscores '_' with a space, all '|' with ' | ', all '-' with ' - ' and then split the resulting string on a single space character. Not sure why you want _ to come as empty string? You must try this and then post another question if it does not work.